# Is this form of dhikr/duaa correct?

Tags: hadith, source-identification, dhikr

Salam, I’m not too sure what this would come under so I’ve assumed and put dhikr. It’s the duaa that you read after Maghrib and Fajr. ‘Allahumma Ajirnee Minannarr’

As a kid I was taught to read it 7 times but a post on Instagram said this is unreliable and not authentic Hadith. Can someone find out if this is true because he then stated 3 times is what Prophet muhammed PBUH read. Jazakallah Khair

Comment: There's a difference between, correctness and authenticity of a dhikr and further between these two and whether it is permissible or not to act upon it. There are many ahadith on dhikr which are neither bound to a time or amount, but are recommended by some people for a time or amount this doesn't mean that they are incorrect or not authentic.

Answer (score 1):

> When you finish the Maghrib prayer, say: "*O Allah, protect me from Hell* (Allahumma a-jirni minan-nar) *seven times*" [...]
>
> <sup>Abu Dawud ([5079](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:5079)), which Ibn Hajar classed Hasan in Nata'ij al-Afkar ([2/326](https://archive.org/details/WAQ101273/02_101274/page/n326/mode/2up?view=theater)), and Shaykh Albani objected in Ad-Da'ifah (4/127-9 - #[1624](https://shamela.ws/book/12762/2342)) - In it is one narrator who is unknown which makes it weak.</sup>
>
> <sup><sup>Nevertheless, there are two other Ahadith which should be rather followed **in general**:</sup></sup>
>
> <sup>In Musnad Abu Ya'la ([6192](https://shamela.ws/book/181/5006)), classed Sahih in As-Sahihah (6/22-5 - #[2506](https://shamela.ws/book/9442/3550)), the Prophet (ﷺ) said:</sup>
>
> "*No slave seeks protection from the Fire seven times in a day except that the Fire says: 'O my Lord, indeed your slave sought protection in You from me, so protect him.' And no slave asks Allah for Paradise seven times in a day except that Paradise says: 'O my Lord, indeed your slave asked for me, so enter him into Paradise.'*"
>
> <sup>Lastly, in At-Tirmidhi ([2572](https://al-maktaba.org/book/782/2572)), which Shaykh Albani classed Sahih in Talaq al-Raghib (4/222), the Prophet (ﷺ) said:</sup>
>
> "*Whoever asks Allah for Paradise three times, Paradise says: 'O Allah, admit him into Paradise', and whoever seeks refuge from the Fire three times, the Fire says: 'O Allah, save him from the Fire.*"

Comment: Jazakallah for the answer

Answer (score 0):

There's a hadith in Sunan abi Dawod [here](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:5079) and referred to it [here](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:5080) again:

> Al-Harith b. Muslim al-Tamimi quoted his father Muslim b. al-Harith al-Tamimi as saying that the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) told him secretly:
> When you finish the sunset prayer, say: 'O Allah, protect me from Hell"
> Allahumma Ajirnee Min(a) an-Naar
> اللهم أجرني من النار
> seven times; for if you say that and die that night, protection from it would be recorded for you; and when you finish the dawn prayer, say it in a similar way, for if you die that day, protection from it would be recorded for you.
> Abu Sa'id told me that al-Harith said: The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said this to us secretly, so we confine it to our brethren.

Sheikh al-Albani qualified it as da'if, while ibn Bazz said it has some issues in the narrator chain, but the hadith is acceptable. Imam ibn Hajar regarded it as hassan. Further there's a version of this hadith in Musnad abi Ya'ala in which no timing was mentioned which al-Albani qualified as sahih.

And further one may find:

> "The Messenger of Allah [SAW] said: 'Whoever asks Allah for Paradise three times, Paradise will say: 'O Allah, admit him to Paradise.' And whoever seeks protection from Hell three times, Hell will say: 'O Allah, protect him from the Fire.'"
> ([Sunan ibn Majah](https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah:4340), [Sunan an-Nasa-i](https://sunnah.com/nasai:5521), [Jami' at-Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:2572))

Which was qualified as sahih by many authorities.

See also fatwa [islamqa #6544](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/6544/the-hadeeth-about-saying-allahumma-ajirni-min-al-nar-seven-times). A detailed analysis of all known sources of the first hadith can be found on [alukah](https://www.alukah.net/sharia/0/81216/).

Comment: Out of the 2 which one would be better recommended since they are both from hadiths. Or is it just a matter of choice?

Comment: @Usman which two are you referring to?

Comment: The Hadith referring to what nabi SAW said and the first Hadith you mentioned which was by Al-Harith b. Muslim al-Tamimi quoted. Apologies if I’m confusing you

Comment: Let's say it this way from what is displayed above in my answer it is safe to say that the hadith of 3 times asking Paradise and 3 times seeking protection from hell is the safest. However if we don't stick on a timing the 7 times asking protection from hell is also fine. The point rather is what is safe to recommend.

Comment: That’s great jazakallah khair.